# Making a animated border animation that goes around in a clockwise circle

Tags: jquery

I am interested in doing [this animation exactly](http://jsfiddle.net/dotsznn0/1/). Except I want this animation to happen in the code when I do something like

`$('#myJqueryAnimation').animate();`

or something like that. I also want the actual border line that is traveling around the button to be a little bit longer in length. This is probably trivial, but I am a novice in CSS, how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `:hover` property, you can add a class name. Then when you want to start or stop your animation, just toggle this class name.

```js
myButton.classList.toggle('animated')
```

```css
button
{
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    
    padding: 10px;
    text-align:center;
    
    background: #ccc;
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

button:after
{
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    top: -10px;
    left: -10px;
    
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    display: block;
    
    content:"";
}

/*********************** .animated instead of :hover */
button.animated:after
{
    -webkit-animation: moveBorder 2s infinite;   
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveBorder
{
    0%{
    
        top:-10px;
        left: -10px;
        
    }
    25%
    {
        top: -10px;
        left: 318px;
    }
    50%
    {
        top: calc(100% - 2px);
        left: 318px;
    }
    75%
    {
        top: calc(100% - 2px);
        left: -10px;
    }
    100%
    {
        top: -10px;
        left: -10px;
    }
}
```

```html
<button id="myButton">Some link</button>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/L3qjv00t/) is a fork of your fiddle as an example.